# Laravel run N Artisan commands in N threads for async runninig N queries

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I write parser and i need it to be multithreading.
I've written code like this:

```js
$filters = [
    'minArea' => 0,
    'maxArea' => 150
];

$stepper = 0;

while ($stepper <= 10) {
    $stepper++;
    
    // Dispatch parse job on current queue
    dispatch(new ParseCianRentJob())->onQueue($this->queues[$currentQueueIndex]);

    // Switch to the next queue
    $currentQueueIndex++;
    if (count($this->queues) == $currentQueueIndex) {
        $currentQueueIndex = 0; // Move on to the start
    }
}

// TRY to run queue workers async
foreach ($this->queues as $queue) {
    Artisan::call('queue:work', [
        '--queue' => $queue,
        '--stop-when-empty' => true,
        '--daemon' => true,
    ]);
}
```

But it runs this artisan commands synchronous. I've tried this:

```js
 foreach ($this->queues as $queue) {
      $process = new Process(['php', 'artisan', 'queue:work', "--queue=$queue"]);
      $process->start();

      if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
          echo 'nope';
      }
      echo $process->getOutput();

}
```

But i always get 'nope' message or just the first queue execs if I cahnge command.

```js
private $queues = [
    'cian_1',
    'cian_2',
    'cian_3',
];
```

So, how can I run `php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty --daemon --query=$$$` in multi processes? In other words, I need to run each job in different processes async

I know there's `Artisan::queue` method. But for this I still need to exec multiple queues for run it really async.